# 404 on refresh with Vue Router and Nginx, How to run java jars on nginx server?

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, nginx

I have a project on an Windows server that produces a 404 error when refreshing or manually typing the URL.

run java jars

router.js

```
{ 
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
                if(store.state.gUserId == '' || !store.state.gUserId) {
                    next('/login');
                }
            },
        },
        { 
            path : "/login", 
            name : "login", 
            component : login , 
            props : true
        },
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        include C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/nonstop/etc/nginx-1.22.1/conf.d/service-url.inc;

        listen       80;
        server_name  mmsdev.kolmarbnh.co.kr;

        ssl_certificate      .crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  .key;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

    # HTTPS server
    #
    server {
        include C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/nonstop/etc/nginx-1.22.1/conf.d/service-url.inc;

        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  mmsdev.kolmarbnh.co.kr;

        ssl_certificate      .crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  .key;

        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass $service_url;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }
    }
}
```

-> example.com/ is working but example.com/login is not working

```
location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            }
```

https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

-> example.com/login is showing but not working
example.com/ is not working

sorry i don't speak english..